# Jmeter write out to a file

Tags: jmeter

I have a selenium script which is running in Jmeter using JUnit sampler.  My selenium program has a few system.pritnln statements which I see it in console when Jmeter runs, how can I write them to a file?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would go for [Sample Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) instead so you could get Username included into .jtl results file, add the code like:

1. In JUnit:

   ```
   JUnitSampler sampler = new JUnitSampler();
   JMeterVariables vars = sampler.getThreadContext().getVariables();
   vars.put("username", your_username_variable);
   vars.put("elapsed", your_total_time_variable);
   sampler.getThreadContext().setVariables(vars);
   ```
2. In JMeter's *user.properties* file:

   ```
   sample_variables=username,elapsed
   ```

If you want a separate file - just replace all your `System.out.println("");` with:

```
FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new File("/path/to/file"),"what you need to write", true);
```

See [How to Use JUnit With JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-junit-jmeter) article for more information on running your JUnit tests with JMeter

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to create a separate file and you can use log file then below statement will do to write in a log file

```
log.info(" TEXT ");
```

If you want to create a separate file, then

```
import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer;

f = new FileOutputStream("c:/output/result.txt", true); 
p = new PrintStream(f); 
p.println(" Hello World "); // update here what you want to write
p.close();
f.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

1: Add JSR223 Sampler to yoour test plan

2: Write below code:

```
FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("D:\\subid.csv",true); //Create New file with name "subid"

BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);

out.write(vars.get("variable1"));//write value of variable 1

out.write(",");

out.write(vars.get("variable2"));//write value of variable 2

out.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));//insert new line

out.close();
fstream.close();
```